# Google Map not rendering Json Data in Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I'm trying to display specific coordinates in a database on a google map with markers. Right now I'm trying to use a simple marker.

Background:

I have a local json file in static/maps/jason_data.json

I'm using google api and I'm using their template here.

```
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

      <head>
        <style>
           #map {
            height: 600px;
            width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }



    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>


 var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(a,b),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

        results = map.data.loadGeoJson('/maps/json_data.json');


      window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
          var coords = results[i].features[0].geometry.coordinates;
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

 </div>
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Error parsing /maps/json_file.json: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
```

An example of the json file

```
{"id48": {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": ["a", "-b"]}, "type": "Point"}], "properties": {"prop1": "property", "id": 48}},...}
```

I'm trying to format the json file through python similar to other GEOJson options.

My apologies I haven't used javascript before.

Comment: it seems you have wrong char `<` in JSON file - or server send HTML with error message instead your data. Better open in browser `http://your_domain/maps/json_file.json` and see what you get. BTW: are you sure it shouldn't be `/static/maps/jason_data.json`

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at that. I have my static_dir set up pretty weird so it's somewhat easier for pathing. The static files not relating to the geocodes are displaying correctly.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but should the json file have var json = dictionary{}

Comment: json file is not javascript file so it can't have `var json = dictionary{}`. It can have only dictionary converted in on string - like in your example. I still think that (as in error message) browser gets not your file with JSON data but some HTML file with message about error - and this file starts with char "<" and you get message `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1` So you have to use browser to try to open your file `http://your_domain/maps/json_file.json` and see what data are send by server to browser.

Comment: I just decided to use render in the urls definition to pass the json, now it's saying it's a text but is displaying correctly.